# C# Task Cancellation

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, blazor

I'm looking for clarification. I'm in a Blazor Server side application. Basically I'm handling an event where a dropdown is kept open, when the user clicks inside an input field inside the dropdown.
I have the following code:

```
private async Task HandleBlur(FocusEventArgs a)
{
    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await Task.Delay(100);
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        show = false;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }, tokenSource.Token);
    await Task.Yield();
    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {

    }
}

private void HandleFocus(FocusEventArgs a)
{
    tokenSource?.Cancel();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    tokenSource.Dispose();
}
```

The delay is necessary because the HandleFocus is triggered after the HandleBlur. If there is no delay, the show variable will be set to false before the Cancel method of the tokenSource can be called. My question is regarding the location of the Task.Delay(100). If I call it inside the task or inside the try block, it does not have any effect and show = false is executed, even though tokenSource.Cancel() should have stopped it.

The following does not work

```
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        await task;
    }
```

or in the Task itself

```
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        show = false;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }, tokenSource.Token);
```

My understanding was that I could cancel the task at any given time?

Comment: If you want to cancel the delay, you need to pass it the token, too. `await Task.Delay(100, tokenSource.Token);`

Comment: What does `Task.Yield` do, and what are you hoping to achieve by using it?

Comment: @Fildor That is not what I meant. I will clarify my question: The delay is necessary because the `HandleFocus` is triggered after the `HandleBlur`. If there is no delay, the show variable will be set to false before the Cancel method of the tokenSource can be called. My question is regarding the location of the `Task.Delay(100)`. If I call it inside the task or inside the try block, it does not have any effect and `show = false` is executed, even though `tokenSource.Cancel()` should have stopped it

Comment: So, you are saying you have a timing problem, don't you?

Comment: Using your current implementation `tokenSource.Cancel()` stops nothing in the `try` block and neither in body of the `Task.Run()`. See my answer proposal.

Comment: @Fildor one could put it down to that.

Comment: @cly It does seem to work somehow... What would be a proper way to implement it? Does `Task.Delay(100, token)` cancel only the wait or everything after it? My guess would be to cancel only the wait. Method Call --> Wait 100ms to see if cancellation is requested --> If Cancellation: do nothing, else show = false

Comment: Yes like that; maybe the `InvokeAsync` call should be in `else` block too. If you call further some user code then pass the token there too to make it possible to respond to cancellation requests there too. See the proposed answer for reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CancellationToken` is a cooperative thing. Calling the `Cancel()` method wont kill or abort anyhing. It just sets the `IsCancellationRequested`  property of the token. You must implement an appropriate logic to query that property value periodically during your task's execution and respond to it as you want.

The builtin methods have that cooperative code implemented. E.g. you should call `Task.Delay(100, token)` instead of `Task.Delay(100)` if you want it to get cancelled.